# Make an array/range of distinct table columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

On an Excel file I was trying to use the BYROW function in a table in order to join two table columns row by row

The function says it requires an array as its first argument, and I haven't been able to find a way to unite them together succesfully. Any ideas?

To give a clearer example:
Say the table has Field 1 and Field 2, my goal is to make the function:

```
=BYROW( *"Table\[Field 1\] united with Table\[Field 2\]"*;LAMBDA(r;TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;r)))
```

Work in any shape or form.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting without some sample data, but from your formula, it seems you need, to do this: `=UNIQUE(HSTACK(Table[Field 1],Table[Field 2]))` if this doesnt help or i have understood wrong, then please post some sample data with expected output using **[Markdown_Table_Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)**

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed

Comment: Thinking back it was so easy I doubt someone will be as silly as me ahah

Comment: Try `=Table\[Field1\]&Table\[Field2\]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have commented above, and it seems from the explanation of your OP, you need to use the following formula instead of the one you are using presently. That said the formula is:

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(Table[Field 1],Table[Field 2]))
```

---

You may need to change the references as well the separators which is completely based on regional settings. So for me, its comma, but for you from the post it seems you need to use semicolon.

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(Table[Field 1];Table[Field 2]))
```

---